# Dropbox integration for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dropbox-api

Is there any API method by which I can dig into all the folders of dropbox and look for a particular kind of files like a pdf or mp3 or txt? Or is there any  search API in which I can pass my search parameter and ask the API to look for  it every folder of dropbox. My task is to load all songs in my app from dropbox  and its a real pain doing it by using the following method

```
[[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];
```

and then keep on checking if the metadata is a directory or a file and if its a file then look for its extension, and if its a directory then again dig into it which can further contain more directories. I have suggested my client to have one folder for our app in which user will drop the songs but he has already denied it and wants to access whole dropbox and filter all the music files in it. I just want to get assured that its not possible before telling my client that its not possible. and if its possible then please throw some light on the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dropbox Core API directly for search:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#search

Dropbox iOS Sync SDK doesn't support all features of Dropbox Core API.

Comment: can i use credentials of DBSession created using Dropbox SDK for sending direct request using search API? I fetched token and secret token number from my DBSession , but only parameter left in search API url is signature method, I dont know from where and how to get that signature method

Comment: The Dropbox iOS Core SDK does support search, via the searchPath method in DBRestClient

Comment: A very useful dropbox wrapper for ios

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AbbieVys/WrapperDropBox

Useful wrapper class for integrating DropBox in IOS